# String cannot be converted to char, how to fix it?

Tags: java, types, compiler-errors, incompatibletypeerror

It says "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char"
How to fix it?
Here is the example.
[image: code as image]

Comment: declare you char yes as string.

Comment: i strongly suggest you to read basics first

Comment: How to declare it as a string? I am beginner

Comment: Always, always post code as text in questions. Screenshots can *occasionally* be useful, but this would be better as code, with an indication of where the error occurs, and the detailed error message below it.

Comment: Try `input.next().charAt(0)`.

Comment: If you're at the stage of not knowing how to declare variables of different types, I would *strongly* urge you to get a good Java book. Stack Overflow is a wonderful site, even for plenty of beginner questions, but it's not a good place to learn the basics of a language.

Comment: Understand, thank you

Comment: Please don't give him suggestion, it is good to give solution.

Comment: **Hint:** a char **Primitive** is just a number mapped to an ASCII Table, a String is an Object not even related in inheritance terms with a primitive char...

Comment: I’d decalre `String yes;` (instead of `char`) and run the loop `while (yes.equals("t"))` (remember double quotes around `t` so Java knows it’s a string).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. (my emphasis) Please paste your code into the question and format it using the `{}` button.

Comment: Thank you, but my teacher asked me to use do-while instead while.

Comment: do-while is a good choice. I intended to suggest you fill in the while condition from my comment at the bottom of you do-while loop (where it says `while(yes=='t')` now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your solution :

```
public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        char yes;
        do {
            System.out.println("Hi");
            yes = s.next().charAt(0);
        } while (yes == 'Y'); // if u enter 'Y' the it will continue

    }
}
```

To exit enter any thing other then `'Y'`